# How to capture a variable from within a while loop/for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm making a little project just to practice arrays/loops. It's basically a bank page that you can sign up and log into. I want to be able to store the user inputs of their username and password into the array lists when they sign up, then when the user logs in - the system will check if the username matches a name in the database (users array list) or if the password matches (passes array list). However, I discovered that the variables aren't being stored in the arrays when I tried testing it by printing out the array list. How do I properly store the user values into the arrays so I can use them later on? Hopefully that all made sense. Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("cutepig.jpg");
        String[] response1 = {"Sign up", "Log in", "Exit"};
        int options01 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Welcome to Beanie's Bank!", "Beanie's Bank", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon, response1, 0);
        ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> passes = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            if (options01 == 0) {
                JTextField username = new JTextField();
                users.add(username.getText());
                JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
                passes.add(password.getText());
                JTextField confpass = new JPasswordField();
                Object[] message = {
                        "Username: ", username,
                        "Password: ", password,
                        "Confirm Password: ", confpass,
                };
                int signup1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Sign up", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (signup1 == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    if (password.getText().equals(confpass.getText()) && !password.getText().isEmpty() && !confpass.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sign up was successful! \n Welcome to Beansie's Bank. \n Please log in to access your account!");
                        break;
                    } else if (password.getText().isEmpty() || confpass.getText().isEmpty() || username.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input cannot be empty, please enter a valid input.");
                        continue;
                    } else if (!password.getText().equals(confpass.getText())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your passwords do not match! Please try again.");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        while(true){
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] message = {
                "Username: ", username,
                "Password: ", password
        };

        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            if (username.getText().equals(users) && password.getText().equals(passes)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login successful, welcome back " + username + ".");
                break;
            } else if (!username.getText().equals(users) && !password.getText().equals(passes)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login failed, please try again.");
                continue;
            }
            else{
            System.out.println("Login canceled");
            continue;
            }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `username` and `password` fields are being added to the `users` and `passes` lists **before** the user has a chance to input their credentials so the fields were empty at that time. You should move it to after checking for the `OK_OPTION`.

```java
while (true) {
    if (options01 == 0) {
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        JTextField confpass = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] message = {
                "Username: ", username,
                "Password: ", password,
                "Confirm Password: ", confpass,
        };
        int signup1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Sign up", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (signup1 == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if (password.getText().equals(confpass.getText()) && !password.getText().isEmpty() && !confpass.getText().isEmpty()) {
                users.add(username.getText());
                passes.add(password.getText());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sign up was successful! \n Welcome to Beansie's Bank. \n Please log in to access your account!");
                break;
            } //... rest of your code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

First is that in here:

```
JTextField username = new JTextField();
users.add(username.getText());
JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
passes.add(password.getText());
```

you are adding username/password to array list before they are actually know. At this point user didnt yet specify its username/password. You should move the lines `users.add(username.getText());` and `passes.add(password.getText());` to after the user has confirmed their input. The fixed code should look like this:

```
int signup1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Sign up", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  if (signup1 == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
     if (password.getText().equals(confpass.getText()) && !password.getText().isEmpty() && !confpass.getText().isEmpty()) {
         users.add(username.getText()); // !!
        passes.add(password.getText()); // !!
```

Second is this code:

```
if (username.getText().equals(users) && password.getText().equals(passes)) {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`users` and `passes` are declared as:

```
    ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> passes = new ArrayList<>();
```

so you cannot compare `username.getText()` or `password.getText()` (a `String`) with any of them. This wont issue a compiler error, or a runtime exception, `equals` will simply always return false here. You should iterate over the array lists and compare the user input to each element. Like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    if (username.getText().equals(users.get(i)) && password.getText().equals(passes.get(i))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login successful, welcome back " + username.getText() + ".");
        break;
    }
}
```